# SQL Server 2016 CTP -> RTM, safe to attach CTP DB files (including SSISDB)?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm uninstalling an expired CTP build and installing RTM, because the CTP -> RTM upgrade path is not supported. Is there any word on:

- Whether it's supported to attach user database files from CTP to RTM.
- Whether it's supported to attach SSISDB from CTP to RTM.
- I assume it's definitely not supported to attach other system databases from CTP to RTM.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely attach any database from a prior build. As soon as you do this, the internal database structure will be automatically upgraded if there are any changes. This includes system databases, but they will not be considered system databases, using this method.

You can still retrieve SQL Server Agent jobs from the old `msdb` database if you need them, as well as anything you wanted from `master`, including things like logins.